# Updating data in JTable when object changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Let's say I have this JTable:

```
 private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
  private JTable table;
  private DefaultTableModel model;

  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
  model.addColumn("Item");
  model.addColumn("ID");
  model.addColumn("Price");
  model.addColumn("Category");

  this.scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
  this.scrollPane1.setBounds(33, 518, 604, 300);
  this.contentPane.add(this.scrollPane1);
  table = new JTable(model);
  this.scrollPane1.setViewportView(table);
```

I have an Item class, so when I create a new instance of Item, I add the items info to the JTable:

```
Item item = new Item("Shovel", 1, 123, "Tools");
model.addRow(new Object[]{item.getItem(), item.getID(), item.getPrice(), item.getCategory()});
```

So far so good.
But if I update the Item, for example change the price from 5 to 10, it is not updated in the JTable. So if I for example do:

```
item.setPrice(10);
```

It doesnt update in the JTable. I've tried calling model.fireTableDataChanged(); and table.repaint(); but none of them works. It seems like the value in the cell is not associated with the objects value? How would I do this? (First time working with JTables).

Any suggestions? Don't be bothered by the lack of methods etc., I just put this together quickly for this post.
EDIT: My Item objects are stored in a HashMap.

Comment: You write 5 on a piece of paper (the object). You also write 5 on another piece of paper (the table model). The price changes, so you erase 5 and replace it by 10 on the first piece of paper (the object). Do you expect the second piece of paper (the table model) to have 10 on it?

Comment: No, which is the point of my question. How do I link the String in the cell to the String in the object?

Comment: What I would do is avoiding the use of DefaultTableModel completely, and use a custom subclass of AbstractTableModel that would get the data from a `List<Item>`. Updating the model would then modify the Item objects directly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my items are stored in a HashMap, because I need to be able to get them using a key. Do you have an example of what you describe?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data. Replace the 2D array by a List<Item>, and implement all the required methods.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not modifying any cell in the table, the `item` object is not associated with your table directly, your making a now values in the table by using the same values from the `item` object.

what you has to do is to update the cell itself then by overriding the below method from `AbstractTableModel` class:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) { //
```

Then call

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my Item objects are stored in a HashMap. I am not quite sure what should go in the overrided methods to be honest.

Comment: You should pass the new value beside the cell location, thats all.